# Htaccess to Nginx Rewrite Conversion

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

htaccess to nginx rewrite conversion help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} apiv01
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

--- edit

I want when access uri GET http://localhost/hospital_project/apiv01/listHospital/3211 can display

```
    {"header":{"code":"401","message":"wrong token"}}
```

I've used the configuration of anilcetin like this:

```
location /hospital_project {
if ($uri ~ "apiv01"){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
        }
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /hospital_project/api.php?params=$1;
        }

}
```

Also i've used the configuration of https://winginx.com/en/htaccess like this:

```
location / {
  rewrite apiv01 /hospital_project/api.php?params=$1;
}
```

But when i access http://localhost/hospital_project/apiv01/listHospital/3211 the output is equal to http://localhost/hospital_project/apiv01 (no effect)

--- edit

Normal if i using http://localhost/hospital_project/api.php?params=apiv01/listHospital/3211

Comment: What is the problem?
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: hi.. i have edited the question. thx

Comment: solve for temporary; i use reverse proxy to apache for this location, but im still curious if using nginx rewrite mode